# Is there a way to not continuously make a new launch configuration when writing python code in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using Eclipse IDE to write all my python code at the moment and there's a feature that's really annoying. Every time I want to run a new script, I have to create a separate launch configuration. This is a bit impractical as I have over 100+ files. Any way of getting round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch, that really seems bad... the plan is actually that you never have to create a launch configuration yourself ;)

There are details on how you're expected to run things in PyDev at: https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html.

Some short details extracted from there:

- `F9` is used to run your program (automatically creates launch/run)
- `Shift+F9` to debug (automatically creates launch/debug)
- `Ctrl+F11` is used to rerun it (note: in `Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching`, set the Launch Operation to `Always launch the previously launched application` so that this works).
- `F11` rerun in debug mode
- `Ctrl+F9` is used to run test-cases (it uses the current text selected to filter the tests, so, you can `Ctrl+Shift+Up` / `Ctrl+Shift+Down` to select the one you want prior to running).
- Pressing `Shift`+`Enter` after `Ctrl+F9` will debug the test launch instead of running it as just `Enter` would do.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm on a laptop however and F9 logs off my profile. I've also tried Ctr + F9, Alt + F9 and Shift + F9. Is there like a hotkeys menu in eclipse?